# If $A \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda(A)=0$ then A has finitely many elements

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

I am trying to determine if $A \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda(A)=0$ then A has finitely many elements

My intuition is that this is FALSE. Because if $A=\mathbb{Q}$ then 
$$\lambda(A)=\lambda(Q_1)+\lambda(Q_2)+...+\lambda(Q_n)$$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$

However on the other hand, then $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable so I am not sure if that affects that it is actually finite

Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: Since the Lebesgue measure of a point, $\lambda (a),\  a\in A$ is $0$ then any infinite set of discrete points will have measure $0$.  $\mathbb Q$ is a good example of this :)  (Countable is the same thing as "countably infinite").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is fine. You have found an infinite set with measure $0$. 
 $\mathbb N$ is another  counter-example.